# Send method as parameter

Tags: c++, class, methods, std-function

I just can't find out the way to call methods of a class without using std::bind, because i need to call this method with parameter inside tryfoo.

```
//simple function  
uint16_t getreg(const uint8_t& num)  
{  
    return 0;  
}
```

Lets suppose that in class ClassItem we have public method

```
uint16_t ClassItem::getregI(const uint8_t &f)  
{  
    return 1;  
}
```

function with callable function

```
void tryfoo (const uint8_t &param, std::function<uint16_t (const uint8_t&)> f)  
{  
// let's suppose that param= got some other value here  
    uint16_t result = f(param);  
}  

void basefunction(ClassItem &A)  
{  
   tryfoo (0, getreg); // Why it's OK  
   tryfoo (0, A.getregI) // And this's NOT  ?
}
```

Comment: It's not OK because C++ designers designed it this way.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::bind`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what the issue is. OP, are you simply asking why the syntax `A.getregI` is not equivalent to a `std::bind`?

Comment: @Acorn i misunderstood the way std::bind is working, but now everything  has become clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `std::function` holds space for one pointer*, and nothing else. Passing just a plain function is possible because it fits in the space of one pointer. This is not possible with a member function from an object because you'd have to store both the pointer to the function and the pointer to the object, and you just can't fit two pointers into the space of one pointer (at least, not safely).

So you have to build a separate object with `std::bind` and pass the pointer to that in. You could just pass the pointer to the member function without binding to an object like so `tryfoo (0, ClassItem::getregI);`, but that wouldn't have access to the `A` object.

*: the details on this is fuzzy, but the overall point still stands.

Comment: `std::function` is not just a pointer. In fact, its size is pretty much unbounded (both at compile time for different implementations and at runtime if you consider the allocations as part of the effective size).

Comment: @Acorn see my footnote, this is an explanation for a new programmer

Comment: If `std::function` were just a pointer, why wouldn't we just use function pointers instead?

Comment: @randomusername Thank you for your explanation, really, now i see how stupid my question is ( my cold makes me dummy)
well, 
  auto f = std::bind (&ClassItem::getregI, &A, std::placeholders::_1)  
 is a solution for me

Comment: @VladSamara or, you can use a lambda instead: `tryfoo (0, [&](const uint8_t &param){ A.getregI(param); });`  `std::bind()` is pretty much deprecated in lieu of lambdas

Comment: @melpomene because it's more like 2 or 3 pointers conveniently rolled into one place that's much easier to use. It just doesn't promise to manage memory for you like `std::vector` does so you gotta be explicit and manually carve out the extra space with `std::bind` and friends.

Comment: I personally use @RemyLebeau suggestion of lambdas, so much nicer.

Comment: @randomusername On the contrary, it actually manages things for you, including allocating memory for whatever state is required/bound. `std::function` was actually designed to simplify that and provide a way to hold any callable. What do you mean?